# SXA Boosting Rules not working

Tags: sxa, content-search

I'm using SXA 1.7 and Sitecore 9, I made a SXA boosting rule to a search scope and it works well on CM(Master Database), I publish the scope and I checked that it's published, but it's not reflecting on CD(Web Database), the required templates is not boosted,everything is published, the search query is the same, I rebuilt the master and the web indexes, but still the problem exists.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "it is not working on CD"? Do you have any errors? Everything (including templates) is published? What is the search query on the CM and on CD server? Have you compared? All the indexes are rebuilt on CD?

Comment: By 'not working' I mean it;s not reflecting, the required templates is not boosted, I don't have any errors, everything is published, the search query is the same, I rebuilt the master and the web indexes.

Comment: Did you rebuild only `sitecore_web_index` and `sitecore_master_index`?

Comment: Yes I rebuilt them only.

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that SXA is using its own indexes - `sitecore_sxa_master_index` and `sitecore_sxa_web_index`?

Comment: Yes, but I'm using SXA 1.7 and Sitecore 9.

Comment: Investigate Search.log and check what search indexes are used. Just to be sure. You can update your question with those queries to put more light on it.

Comment: I found this at the Search.log, this is the only thing regarding the boosting at the logs :
 Processing Field Name : __boosting rules. Resolving Multiple Field found on Solr Field Map. No matching template field on index field name '__boosting_rules', return type 'List`1' and field type ''

Comment: It looks like there might be something wrong with Solr schema.

Comment: I tried populating the solr schema but still not worked, I tried resetting the IIS on the three CDs servers we have, it works on one CD server, but the other two CDs servers was still not reflected.