# Indexing Boost value, Boosting rules, and Facets

Tags: indexing

I'm using Sitecore 9.0 (Solr 6.6.2) and am confused by the "Indexing" section found on items.

Through experimentation I've found that entering a number may or may not actually change the search results listing, but mostly not. I'm not sure how the facets are supposed to do in this section.

Is this a feature that requires SXA to work? I've seen something similar called "Boosting" in [another question](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/18643/sxa-boosting-rules-not-working), but the appearance is different. I've read [some documentation](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/93/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/search-result-boosting.html) but I'm confused whether there needs to be additional configuration in the include files before this section will work.

I'm just trying to figure out how to get this to work, and whether the documentation I've read is even relevant or if it's for something else. Thank you for your time and help!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solr 6.5 and above does not support index time boosting. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-6819. You can include the boost parameter while indexing, as Sitecore does, and it is simply ignored by Solr.

Sitecore has [partially acknowledged](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/search-result-boosting.html) this in the documentation, however they incorrectly state that support was removed in Solr 7, when it was in fact remove in Solr 6.5. This means that boosting is broken as of 9.0, not 9.1.

Comment: So if I'm understanding this correctly, the above feature does not work any longer in Sitecore because the feature was deprecated in Solr 6.5?

Comment: @Justin That is correct. Sitecore will send the boost parameter to Solr, and Solr will silently ignore it.